# How long an Async Request keep alive in server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I'm implement Comet in asp.net, and I'm using asynchronous post back to keep request alive in server. But I don't know how long can keep a request alive in server, Some guys said that need to end async request because server will alert 404 error if I keep the request too long.
How long can I keep async requests alive in server ? Is there limit time or un-limit time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e99daa45-4a87-465b-86f5-820fea9d1117.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e99daa45-4a87-465b-86f5-820fea9d1117.aspx)

**Edit**

Comet implementation (if you don't want do it it yourself)

https://github.com/nmosafi/aspcomet

Comment: Thanks for ur explain, but my question is what exactly limit time I can keep request alive in server ?